# O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity way to see if two strings are permutations of each other

Tags: string, performance, big-o

Is there an algorithm that can see if two strings are permutations of each other with O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity?

Comment: Note that `n` is the length of the strings

Comment: You probably want to search for string anagrams, not permutations.

Comment: I seriously doubt so, as even answer of Ayon is O(log(n)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure there is a very nice way. You have to use count sort for this. There is no reason to generate prime numbers at all. Here is a C code snippet that describes the algorithm:

```
bool is_permutation(string s1, string s2) {
    if(s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;

    int count[256]; //assuming each character fits in one byte, also the authors sample solution seems to have this boundary
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++) count[i]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++) { //count the digits to see if each digits occur same number of times in both strings
        count[ s1[i] ]++; 
        count[ s2[i] ]--;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<256;i++) { //see if there is any digit that appeared in different frequency
        if(count[i]!=0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:** (I decided to add this after some comments related to order of my program)

The Lets try to calculate the time complexity of the algorithm I have used in my program:

```
n = max len of strings
m = max allowed different characters, assuming will having all consecutive ascii value in range [0,m-1]
Time complexity: O(max(n,m)) 
Memory Complexity O(m)
```

Now assuming m is a constant here the order becomes

```
Time complexity: O(n) 
Memory Complexity O(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple program I wrote in java that gives the answer in `O(n)` for time complexity and `O(1)` for space complexity. It works by mapping every character to a prime number and then multiplying together all of the characters in the string's prime mappings. If the two strings are permutations then they should have the same unique characters each with the same number of occurrences.

Here is some sample code that accomplishes this:

```
// maps keys to a corresponding unique prime
static Map<Integer, Integer> primes = generatePrimes(255); // use 255 for
                                                        // ASCII or the
                                                        // number of
                                                        // possible
                                                        // characters

public static boolean permutations(String s1, String s2) {
    // both strings must be same length
    if (s1.length() != s2.length())
         return false;

     // the corresponding primes for every char in both strings are multiplied together
     int s1Product = 1;
     int s2Product = 1;

     for (char c : s1.toCharArray())
         s1Product *= primes.get((int) c);

     for (char c : s2.toCharArray())
         s2Product *= primes.get((int) c);

     return s1Product == s2Product;

 }

 private static Map<Integer, Integer> generatePrimes(int n) {

     Map<Integer, Integer> primes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

     primes.put(0, 2);

     for (int i = 2; primes.size() < n; i++) {
         boolean divisible = false;

         for (int v : primes.values()) {
             if (i % v == 0) {
                 divisible = true;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if (!divisible) {
             primes.put(primes.size(), i);
             System.out.println(i + " ");
         }
     }

     return primes;

 }
```

Comment: Clever solution, even if it isn't the simplest

Comment: @JensRoland Thanks!!